# How to fix 'urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found'

Tags: python

Next is the code:

```
import urllib
url=r'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist\train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'demo.zip')
```

Next is the error:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a702ad6c8455> in <module>()
      1 import urllib
      2 url=r'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist\train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
----> 3 urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'demo.zip')

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    246     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    247 
--> 248     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    249         headers = fp.info()
    250 

    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):
    530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 532             response = meth(req, response)
    533 
    534         return response

    640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    641             response = self.parent.error(
--> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 
    644         return response

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    562             http_err = 0
    563         args = (dict, proto, meth_name) + args
--> 564         result = self._call_chain(*args)
    565         if result:
    566             return result

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

so bad request,can you help me..
this error not for code.i think about my browser or urllib module bug.

Answer (score 0):

The url should read:

```
http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
```

You have a backslash after mnist causing it to be interpreted as a tab.